# Can we deploy a custom WebPart on a standalone SharePoint server?

Tags: feature-activation, standalone

I installed SharePoint 2013 Foundation and during the installation I choose standalone mode. So when I explored the newly created site features,there were only few features.

**Question** : Can I now develop custom WebParts and  deploy them on to the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, you can deploy custom webparts on SharePoint installed on a Standalone server as well as on a Farm server. In fact, many development environments are built on Standalone server.

There's been a discussion on [Using a development farm or standalone?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26725/using-a-development-farm-or-standalone) so you can look at it for more opinions.

One thing you should note, if you need User Profile Synchronization for any reason then Standalone installation will not be adequate.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are referring to deploying solutions as wsp files, yes you can deploy those on SharePoint irrespective of its deployment as standalone or farm.

Comment: @noah_dvlpr Please accept one of the answers and upvote the other if you found them helpful.